# Print Braille characters to cmd c++

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

For one programm I need to output Braille characters to a console.

I found a way to output unicode characters using code like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "io.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout<<L"ĐĄßĞ"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And changing font of cmd to Lucida Console.

However, there is a problem that Braille characters aren't displayed is such a way. Actually, I can't even copy and paste them to code, because they appear blank. In Linux everything works(I can see, copy and paste these characters), but I need Windows application.

I guess there is some posiblity to use codes of this characters, I tried this way, but had no success.

Can anybody help me with this task?

Comment: Lucida Console does not support the Braile characters (https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1262). Braile is category others, which is not listed. Try with a different unicode font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll need to install a monospaced font that supports Unicode.  To try this out, I used FreeMono.ttf from http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Braille.html.
2. After installing the font, edit the registry to add the font to the console's list of fonts: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont.  There should be a `0` and `00` entry for Lucida Console and Consolas.  Add another zero to the Value name for each font you want.  I added `000` and set to `FreeMono`.
3. Restart the console, then edit its properties to choose the font.  On Windows 10, you may have to enabled "Legacy Mode" in the console properties and restart the console before the font shows up.  After selecting it, you can turn legacy mode back off again.

Here's the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "io.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout<<L"\u2876\u2877\u2878"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output (screenshot):

[image: Screenshot of functional Braille output]

Note: The font I chose didn't display ASCII nicely, so I don't recommend it, but the Braille was fine.

Comment: thank you for your answer very much. It works and as far as I understood there is no way to add custom font from inside c++. Also FreeMono is the probably the only mono-space font with braille character set, so your answer is really the only possible solution.

Comment: This does not work for me on Windows 10 21H1. I don't see the font in the list

Comment: @Thomas Since this question was answered there is a new console interface.  You must enable "Legacy Console" mode before the font shows up.  Oddly, a font I installed when my system was still Windows 7 still shows up in non-Legacy mode, but only FreeMono vanishes from the list once I disable legacy mode again.  Must have migrated during the upgrade.  The selected font stayed FreeMono, though.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Legacy mode did it