# Displaying unicode characters in Windows 10 cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, unicode, windows-10

I want to type and print in windows 10 CMD sinhala unicode characters. but it just display question mark surrounded by a square for each sinhala character i type.
Is there any mechanism to display exact unicode characters in windows console?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the registry settings for the cmd console (run regedit). Unfortunately, I am uncertain exactly which value you should enter for the font family, since it is a number.

The screen shot below shows my registry settings for a font of 'Courier New', which somehow translates to 30 (hexidecimal, 48 in base 10) in the registry. Hopefully you can experiment some and determine what number corresponds to a Sinhala font you have installed on your machine.
[image: Registry Screen Shot]

Additionally, you can select fonts using the cmd window's property dialog, illustrated in the screen shot below. Possibly you already have a font installed that you can use:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already done 1-3 since you can already type Sinhala, but you need a supporting font. Try the following:

1. Go to Region & language settings.
2. Add a language and select, Sinhala.
3. Click the language, Select Options, and you can select a keyboard type.
4. For Chinese, I was able to add a language pack, which gave me console fonts that support Chinese.  I don't see that option for Sinhala.  You may have to manually install a monospace font that support Sinhala.  I couldn't find one, but if you do, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33527725/235698) explains how to install it.