# Text art/Banner Not Appearing In cmd Prompt (Unicode/ASCII)

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, cmd, unicode

I would like this to appear in cmd prompt either when I execute the file from cmd prompt or by running from a batch file:

```
⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⠃⠄⢀⣴⡾⠃⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⠺⠟⠛⠛⠛⠛⠻⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣤⡀⠄
⢸⣿⣿⣿⡟⢀⣴⣿⡿⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷
⢸⣿⣿⠟⣴⣿⡿⡟⡼⢹⣷⢲⡶⣖⣾⣶⢄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣼⣿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⢸⣿⢫⣾⣿⡟⣾⡸⢠⡿⢳⡿⠍⣼⣿⢏⣿⣷⢄⡀⠄⢠⣾⢻⣿⣸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⡿⣡⣿⣿⡟⡼⡁⠁⣰⠂⡾⠉⢨⣿⠃⣿⡿⠍⣾⣟⢤⣿⢇⣿⢇⣿⣿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣱⣿⣿⡟⡐⣰⣧⡷⣿⣴⣧⣤⣼⣯⢸⡿⠁⣰⠟⢀⣼⠏⣲⠏⢸⣿⡟⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⡟⠁⠄⠟⣁⠄⢡⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣦⣼⢟⢀⡼⠃⡹⠃⡀⢸⡿⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟
⣿⣿⠃⠄⢀⣾⠋⠓⢰⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⣿⣿⣾⣅⢔⣕⡇⡇⡼⢁⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢣
⣿⡟⠄⠄⣾⣇⠷⣢⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣭⣀⡈⠙⢿⣿⣿⡇⡧⢁⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢏⣾
⣿⡇⠄⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⢻⠇⠄⠄⢿⣿⡇⢡⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣏⣼⣿
⣿⣷⢰⣿⣿⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢰⣧⣀⡄⢀⠘⡿⣰⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⣼⣿⣿
⢹⣿⢸⣿⣿⠟⠻⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣭⣉⣤⣿⢈⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠏⣾⣹⣿⣿
⢸⠇⡜⣿⡟⠄⠄⠄⠈⠙⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⣱⣻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⠁⢳⠃⣿⣿⣿
⠄⣰⡗⠹⣿⣄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⣅⣥⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠋⠄⠄⣾⡌⢠⣿⡿⠃
⠜⠋⢠⣷⢻⣿⣿⣶⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⣛⣥⣾⣿⠿⠟⠛⠉⠄⠄
```

I created a text file for it and tried to open that txt file within the batch file but it shows a bunch of gibberish. Here is the batch file code:

```
@ECHO OFF
Art Gallery
color 0b
mode 300
ECHO Welcome to Art!
pause>null
cls


ECHO this is art
ECHO.
type Test1.txt
pause>null
del null
```

I installed a braille font and added it to the registry but didn't appear under properties. I'm not too familiar with scripting so feel to give constructive feedback.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you writing a bash script or a BAT file? Please don't select random tags.

Comment: Nice *ascii art* by the way, but the rest is not nice :-)

Comment: The `NUL` device only has one `L`.

Comment: They weren't random sorry I thought they were related. My mistake.

Comment: Why would someone change his console font to Braille just to see this and then change it back so that CMD works as before? I don't really get it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller basically I would like this to output to the cmd prompt console if possible. It's for some content I'm creating. If it can be done I would greatly appreciate the help but if it cannot then I can figure something else out. Thank you.

Comment: @Squashman thank you for the constructive feedback I'll fix it in my bat file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a pointer by @Squashman we can add a small system FONT command, one of many by [Jean-François Larvoire](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib) to switch console fonts on the fly.

[image]

You will need to ensure **Font.exe** from that lib is found in your current path or else add the full path into the code (remove the rem before set path). Note although I used MS Gothic others will also work and you can also set  font style such as weight or use different character width/height.

```
@echo off & cls & Title Face
::ÿþ

REM for this usage setlocal is surplus to requirement but included if needed later
rem setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion

rem set "path=c:\wherever font.exe is e.g c:\utils\systools;%path%"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('Font -s') do @set "OLD_Font=%%f"
Font "MS Gothic"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:."  %%c in ('ChCp') do @set "OLD_ChCp=%%~c"
if not defined OLD_ChCp set "OLD_ChCp=850"

ChCp 65001>nul
echo/

for %%e in (
⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⠃⠄⢀⣴⡾⠃⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠈⠺⠟⠛⠛⠛⠛⠻⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣤⡀⠄
⢸⣿⣿⣿⡟⢀⣴⣿⡿⠁⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⣸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷
⢸⣿⣿⠟⣴⣿⡿⡟⡼⢹⣷⢲⡶⣖⣾⣶⢄⠄⠄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣼⣿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⢸⣿⢫⣾⣿⡟⣾⡸⢠⡿⢳⡿⠍⣼⣿⢏⣿⣷⢄⡀⠄⢠⣾⢻⣿⣸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⡿⣡⣿⣿⡟⡼⡁⠁⣰⠂⡾⠉⢨⣿⠃⣿⡿⠍⣾⣟⢤⣿⢇⣿⢇⣿⣿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣱⣿⣿⡟⡐⣰⣧⡷⣿⣴⣧⣤⣼⣯⢸⡿⠁⣰⠟⢀⣼⠏⣲⠏⢸⣿⡟⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⡟⠁⠄⠟⣁⠄⢡⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣦⣼⢟⢀⡼⠃⡹⠃⡀⢸⡿⢸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟
⣿⣿⠃⠄⢀⣾⠋⠓⢰⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⣿⣿⣾⣅⢔⣕⡇⡇⡼⢁⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢣
⣿⡟⠄⠄⣾⣇⠷⣢⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣭⣀⡈⠙⢿⣿⣿⡇⡧⢁⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢏⣾
⣿⡇⠄⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⢻⠇⠄⠄⢿⣿⡇⢡⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣏⣼⣿
⣿⣷⢰⣿⣿⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢰⣧⣀⡄⢀⠘⡿⣰⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⣼⣿⣿
⢹⣿⢸⣿⣿⠟⠻⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣭⣉⣤⣿⢈⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠏⣾⣹⣿⣿
⢸⠇⡜⣿⡟⠄⠄⠄⠈⠙⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⣱⣻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⠁⢳⠃⣿⣿⣿
⠄⣰⡗⠹⣿⣄⠄⠄⠄⢀⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠟⣅⣥⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠋⠄⠄⣾⡌⢠⣿⡿⠃
⠜⠋⢠⣷⢻⣿⣿⣶⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⣛⣥⣾⣿⠿⠟⠛⠉⠄⠄
) do @echo %%e

echo/
pause

REM tidy-up
Font %OLD_Font%
set OLD_Font=
ChCp %OLD_ChCp%>nul
set OLD_ChCp=
endlocal
REM exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a text file that contains the Braille characters from the Unicode block U+28xx.

While I've not used a braille font yet, I think it is there to represent the normal characters (A-Z etc.) in Braille, meaning: the ASCII character 65 or `A` will be displayed as `⠁`. This makes it easier for non-blind humans to switch between "readable" and Braille text. They can type as usual.

The gibberish probably looked like this. This is a UTF-8 file printed on codepage 850:

```
E:\>type text1.txt
Ôó©Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐ÔáâÔáäÔóÇÔú┤Ôí¥ÔáâÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáêÔá║ÔáƒÔáøÔáøÔáøÔáøÔá╗Ôó┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐ÔúÂÔúñÔíÇÔáä
Ôó©Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐ÔíƒÔóÇÔú┤Ôú┐Ôí┐ÔáüÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔú©Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐ÔúÀ
Ôó©Ôú┐Ôú┐ÔáƒÔú┤Ôú┐Ôí┐ÔíƒÔí╝Ôó╣ÔúÀÔó▓ÔíÂÔúûÔú¥ÔúÂÔóäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔáäÔóÇÔú╝Ôú┐Ôó┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐Ôú┐
```

With above in mind, you could change the codepage to UTF-8, i.e.

```
chcp 65001
```

but it will not help much, since most of the Console fonts don't have the Braille characters built-in and the result will look like this

```
E:\>type text1.txt
☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒
☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒
☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒☒
```

If you happen to have Asian language support installed, you'll see that changing the codepage indeed helps. The MS Gothic and NSimSun fonts come with Braille but has some issues in line 6 and 11, maybe some combining diacritics? I don't exactly know and I'm not familiar with Unicode to that level.

[image: MS Gothic]

Comment: Wow, that's a way better result than what I could get. I greatly appreciate the help! Do you think installing a Braille font might work? Because I installed one but it didn't appear under my fonts. Probably didn't do something right in the registry. Worst comes to worse I can use this. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @tlbiro: is that font available online? What kind of font is it (TTF, Monospaced)?

Comment: Here's the link to the one I downloaded:

http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Braille.html

I downloaded the first one, UBraille

Comment: @tlbiro I think you would be better off with the FreeMono font.

Comment: Got it. Does it matter which ttf file I download? And for the font to appear in properties do I need to reboot my PC?

Comment: @Squashman: did you find a FreeMono font that makes it into the CMD Properties box?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I was basing that assumption off of this [StackOverFlow accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33527725/1417694).

Comment: I installed the FreeMono and modified the registry as well. Going to reboot my PC and see if anything changes.

Comment: @tlbiro: a reboot should not be needed. Just restart CMD. Reboot didn't help for me

Comment: @ThomasWeller you're right still not working. Might just have to make due with that.

Comment: I was able to remove the question marks but messing with the txt file. It'll work I thank you for all of your help!!

Comment: I figured it out.  You need to enable "Use Legacy Console".  Once you do that and restart the console the FreeMono font is selectable.

Comment: Got the same issue with Line 6 and 11 even when using FreeMono.

Comment: @KJ we ahd a discussion about this on DosTips.com a few years ago.  I think one of the users over there wrote a small console utility that he could call in the middle of his script that would let him switch fonts mid script.